# JAX-RS CXF Exception wrapping

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, cxfrs

I would like to add an ExceptionMapper to CXF (2.6.1) which not only communicates the Response code, but also ships the exception in the payload format (I'm using JSON for now).

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper
        implements
            ExceptionMapper<MyException>
{
...
@Override
public Response toResponse(MyException mex)
{
//I need something here which can convert mex object to JSON and ship it in response
// I want this to be de-serialized on client

//the following returns the status code
return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
}
...
}
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use @Produces to serialize your object to JSON like:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

And then `return Response.ok().entity(OBJECT).build();`

The way that you can test your service:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
ClientResponse response = service.path(ADDRESS).type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
String s = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(s); 

private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(SERVER ADDRESS).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I would like to return status 500 or 400 but not 200's. Is there a way for that ?

Comment: Figured it out. It is this way 
Response.ok(mex,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

Comment: On the client side, do I have to add an interceptor ? Seems like a non-200 response is getting blocked at my servlet

Comment: No it should not be blocked. Are you using Tomcat as your servlet?

Comment: Yes it is tomcat. and yea.. I'm getting an exception of type org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ServerWebApplicationException
How do I get "MyException" from it ?

Comment: maybe because you wrote : `status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)`. we need to have more details of your code to catch your exception. you can ask it as a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14535/discussion-between-chris-and-ali)