# JAX RS CXF Interceptor for throwing client specific exceptions

Tags: java, exception, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I have a server exposing set of classes as RESTful services. I understand that we could use [ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691815/jax-rs-cxf-exception-wrapping) for passing the exception to the client. There are few checked-exceptions that are shared between client and server. However in some of my services, I have few checked-exceptions which are not available in client JVM.

I understand that changing the endpoint to make sure that the checked-exception is handled properly fixes the issue.

But, I would like to do it at interceptor layer for two reasons:

- It would be a single place where I can handle all the invocations that lead to the checked-exception.
- It would be a big refactoring work owing to current release dates.

Looking at [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html), I understand that I have to extend `AbstractPhaseInterceptor` and override `handleMessage()`

```
public class MyOutExceptionInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public AttachmentInInterceptor() {
        //Which phase to call here ??
        super(Phase.POST_INVOKE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        //Check from message that it contains an exception of MyCheckedException.class
        //Create an exception that client can understand

    }
}
```

How do I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but I also had this problem and came up with this solution. So for future reference:

Override handleFault instead, inside:

```
Exception fault = message.getContent(Exception.class);
Exception exception = fault.getCause();
YourOwnFault newFault = new YourOwnFault("bla bla bla");
message.setContent(Exception.class, newFault);
```

In other words: extract the fault, get the exception as the cause, create a new fault and insert int.

Comment: You're not using `exception` variable. Why are you getting it then?

Comment: Probably to use it in the constructor of YourOwnFault instead of "bla bla bla bla".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
 // Map exception
    Exception exception = message.getContent(Exception.class);
    Exception mappedException = mapper.map(exception);

    Fault fault = exception instanceof Fault ? (Fault) exception : null;
    if (fault == null)
    {
        fault = new Fault(exception);
        message.setContent(Exception.class, fault);
     }
    fillInFaultDetails(fault, exception);
}
```

This is actually a snippet from our code (I omitted the mapping/filling in detaisl for brevity; key things to do is to replace the message content.). As for the phase - we run it at POST_LOGICAL; POST_INVOKE may work as well.

By the way - not sure what's your use case, but I don't like using faults to communicate business exceptions (in my mind faults indicate a general message processing error rather than a business logic exception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm getting a RuntimeException at `fault = new Fault(exception);` in the chained Interceptors with this code.

Comment: What sort of exception this is?